# Apex Scatter Chart - show other data values on graph?

Tags: visualforce

I built a scatter graph via the standard reporting functionality.  It's decent, but the client wants some additional filtering, so I'm building it in VF.  Step 1 is to create the graph, so I'm using apex:scatterSeries.  However I notice something that is present in the standard graph that I can't figure out how to do in the apex/vf version.

Each point on the graph represents two values on an Account object.  I want the User to be able to see which Account is associated with each point.  Is there a way to do this?  In the standard graph, you see it when you mouse-over a point.  But I'm not seeing this option for the custom graph.  This seems so simple though - so I'm sure I'm just not finding it.  How do I do it?

It would be ideal if the third value could be visible without mouse-over - then via toggle I could hide it or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `rendererFn` available for `<apex:chartTips`. This attribute specifies the name of a JavaScript function that augments or overrides tooltip rendering for chart tips.

First you have to nest an `apex:chartTips` tag inside your `<apex:scatterSeries` tag to use `rendererFn` attribute. This adds the flexibility to show different attributes in chart tip available in Data class. Here is an example.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController2">
    <apex:chart height="480" width="640" data="{!data}">
        <apex:scatterSeries xField="NumberOfEmployees" yField="Industry" markerType="circle" markerSize="3">
            <apex:chartTips height="60" width="200" rendererFn="renderChartTip"  />
        </apex:scatterSeries>
        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="bottom" fields="NumberOfEmployees" title="No of Employees" grid="true" />
        <apex:axis type="Category" position="left" fields="Industry" title="Industry" grid="true"/>
    </apex:chart>
    <script>
    function renderChartTip(klass, item) {
        var m = item.storeItem;
        this.setTitle(m.get('Name'));
        this.update(''
                + '<table>'
                + '<tr><td><b>Industry : </b>&nbsp;' + m.get('Industry') + '</td></tr>'
                + '<tr><td><b>NumberOfEmployees : </b>&nbsp;' + m.get('NumberOfEmployees') + '</td></tr>'
                + '</table>'
                );
    }
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Controller Class

```
...............
...............
    public class Data {
        public String Industry { get; set; }
        public Integer NumberOfEmployees { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Data(String Industry,String Name, Integer NumberOfEmployees) {
            this.Industry = Industry;
            this.NumberOfEmployees = NumberOfEmployees;
            this.Name = Name;
        }
    }
...............
...............
```

Scatter Chart

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks so much for your response!!